# Remove leading None items from a Numpy array or Python List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a NumPy array

```
[None, None, None, None, 1, 2, None, 4, None]
```

The output I want is

```
[1, 2, None, 4, None]
```

I wrote this while loop but there is something wrong I guess

```
index = 0
while(numpyArray[index] is None):
    numpyArray = np.delete(numpyArray, index)
    index += 1
```

The output I am getting is

```
[None, None, 1, 2, None, 4, None]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that after you delete an item at position `index`, all subsequent indices will be shifted to the left by `1`:

```
 0  1  2  3
[a, b, c, d]
```

deleting at `index == 1` will cause:

```
 0  1  2
[a, c, d]
```

so that right after the deletion `c` and `d` have index `-1` of what they had before the deletion.
The indexing is always contiguous.

---

So, in your code you first delete the item at position 0, all indexes gets shifted by `-1` and when you advance the `index`, you are now considering not the second element (the one that originally was at `index == 1`) but the the third element (the one that originally was at `index == 2`), etc.

If you leave out the `index += 1` line, the code should work.

---

Finally, please note that NumPy arrays are not particularly efficient at resizing. Python `list`s are generally faster at resizing.

Comment: I can't accept it @norok2 because of low reputation but it works, Thank you so much!! :D

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't delete elements from a list (or, as it happens, numpy.array) while iterating over it. Instead, create a copy:

```
import itertools
newArray = np.array(list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x is None, numpyArray)))
```

Comment: The original code was not iterating over it, though. That would have been something like `for item in items: ...`

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to do this in python, try use one of the following

```
numpyArray = [i for i in numpyArray if i is not None]
```

or

```
numpyArray = np.array(list(filter(lambda i: i is not None, numpyArray)))
```

Comment: These will remove **all** `None`s, not just leading ones.